# Cygwin path to /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32 directory?

Tags: cygwin

I am having trouble executing a program located in the "C:\Program Files (x86) directory in Windows from within Cygwin.  Anyone know the trick to getting this to work?

```
jboss@QA024 /cygdrive/C/jboss/EAP-6.0.1/jboss-eap-6.0/bin
$ wgetexe="/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/wget.exe --help"

jboss@QA024 /cygdrive/C/jboss/EAP-6.0.1/jboss-eap-6.0/bin
$ bash $wgetexe
bash: /cygdrive/C/Program: No such file or directory

jboss@QA024 /cygdrive/C/jboss/EAP-6.0.1/jboss-eap-6.0/bin
$ bash "$wgetexe"
bash: /cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/wget.exe --help: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
wgetexe="/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32/wget.exe"
"$wgetexe" --help
```

Since it's an executable, you don't want to pass it as an argument to bash, which will try to execute it as a script. Since it has spaces in the path name, you need to quote the name so the shell doesn't try to execute `cygdrive/C/Program` with invalid arguments.

You should also be able to add the directory to your `$PATH`:

```
PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/C/Program Files (x86)/GnuWin32"
```

Keep in mind that GnuWin32 programs are Windows executables, and any file paths they use will be interpreted using Windows syntax. Cywin executables (anything that uses `cygwin1.dll`) use Cygwin path syntax.

Better yet, install the Cygwin version of `wget` and just invoke it as `wget --help`.

For example, if you're using the GnuWin32 `wget`, you might use:

```
wget -O "C:\cygwin\home\yourname\output-file" "$url"
```

whereas with the Cygwin `wget` you might use:

```
wget -O "/home/yourname/output-file" "$url"
```

I've always found it easiest to use Cygwin executables from Cygwin whenever possible.

Comment: Thanks.  Your advice helped me get it straightened out.  I am trying to get Jenkins to SSH into Cygwin on a windows box and run wget.  I got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it always worked or me.

```
wgetexe="/cygdrive/C/Program\ Files\ \(x86)/GnuWin32/wget.exe"
"$wgetexe" --help
```