# ubuntu clone git repository on windows server

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, msysgit

Using windows 2008 R2 64 bit, I've installed **msysgit** & **cygwin**. The server has a public ip. I've my application's source code in

```
C:\repos\eCat\Raw.git
```

and I want to make that Raw folder a repository, so using the git bash I've entered the following commands (inside Raw folder):

```
$ git --bare init
```

and I get the following output:

```
Initialized Empty Git repository in c:/repos/eCat/Raw.git/
```

I Installed **bitvise ssh server** and assigned a windows local server with restrictions limited to that **repos** folder & tested the ssh connection from ubuntu to the windows server which works as it is supposed to.

Now I want to remotely download the source code from the windows server on my ubuntu device and work on it and then commit & push the changes back to server.

I don't know what should I run in terminal to pull the source code, something like:

```
git clone ssh://username@remoteServerIp:path/to/source/code???
```

I'm quite new to using git and I've followed a tutorial on this but now I'm stuck. Any kind of explaining or help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** I've tried the following (not sure if it's correct)

```
git clone ssh://git@79.143.84.170/~/c/repos/eCat/Raw
```

and got the following error:

```
'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

isn't cygwin is supposed to handle sh files on windows?

Comment: @Menefee check the post plaese, I've updated it.

Comment: You're close.  The message "Initialized Empty Git repository" means that there is no local repo.  You'll have to clone one first. Try running "git clone git://username@remoteip/repos/eCat/Raw.git"

Comment: Are you sure you type `ssh` instead of `sh`?

Comment: @Kangcor when I typed ssh it says Cloning into Raw... then it asks for the server password. so yes I'm pretty sure about it. is the way I put the path of the source is correct?

Comment: Well maybe try using an absolute path instead the /~, but i think that's not the problem

Comment: @arashmoeen  authenticate yourself or sudo.  Then run git clone ssh://79.143.84.170/~/c/repos/eCat/Raw.git

Comment: @Menefee tried sudo git clone ssh://git@79.143.84.170/~/c/repos/eCat/Raw.git  and it didn't work. gave the same error again

Comment: keeps saying that 'sh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, I have a sh file called "gitcmdhelper.sh" inside the Git/bin folder which has $* inside. just saying

Comment: @arashmoeen the `sh ` means some shell file is trying to be executed. This would work from a `git-bash`, but not otherwise. If you want to setup git server on windows machine, check this github link: https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/wiki/Setting-up-a-Git-server-on-Windows-using-Git-for-Windows-and-CopSSH

Comment: @mu無 isn't cygwin supposed to make the sh file known for windows?

Comment: You probably need to set up cygwin a bit.  try :set shell=\"C:\Program\ Files\Git\bin\sh.exe\"  ... or whatever path to sh.exe is appropriate.

Comment: @Menefee If I'm not mistaken I should run that in cygwin teminal, but 1 problem I'm facing, since the server is 64bit and Git is installed in **Program Files (x86)**.. although I'm escaping spaces with backslash \ but still it says `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token`('`

Comment: First google (cygwin set path "Program Files (x86).")search returned this at the top :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923849/cygwin-path-to-cygdrive-c-program-files-x86-gnuwin32-directory  I suggest you stop and take some time to thoroughly investigate the problem.  Leverage Google.  It will pave your career.